# Why does PATH differ when I connect to my Docker container with ssh or with exec/attach?

Tags: docker, ssh, server, pytorch, environment-variables

I build a Docker image based on the following Dockerfile:

```
ARG PYTORCH="1.6.0"
ARG CUDA="10.1"
ARG CUDNN="7"

FROM pytorch/pytorch:${PYTORCH}-cuda${CUDA}-cudnn${CUDNN}-devel

ENV TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="6.0 6.1 7.0+PTX"
ENV TORCH_NVCC_FLAGS="-Xfatbin -compress-all"
ENV CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$(dirname $(which conda))/../"

# SSH SERVER
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server sudo -y
RUN echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd

WORKDIR /

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["service ssh start"]
```

I launch the Docker container with

```
docker run -it -d -p 7220:22 --name ssh-server-test ssh-server-image /bin/bash
```

If I connect to the container with `docker exec -it ssh-server-test /bin/bash` or `docker attach ssh-server-test`, I get the `PATH` I expect:

```
root@9264667daf83:/# echo $PATH
/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

**However**, if I start an ssh server with

```
root@9264667daf83:/# service ssh start
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                                                                                                                                [ OK ] 
root@9264667daf83:/#
```

and I connect to the Docker container through ssh as root, then the `PATH` is completely different!

```
root@9264667daf83:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Why? And how can I get the right `PATH` variable also when I connect to the container through ssh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment variable you are asking of has been set by docker itself, using `ENV` clause. Check the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/Dockerfile#L72) of the initial Dockerfile.

Variables that are set by `ENV` exist on the build stage, run, and when you exec into a running container. More [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env).

But when you SSH into the container, the usual Linux path for sourcing files like `~/.bashrc` is working. But there is no `PATH` with conda, nvidia, etc in these files.

As a workaround, you can patch `/root/.bashrc` on the build stage with the corresponding `export PATH`. For example, you can add to the `Dockerfile`

```
RUN echo 'export PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc
```

**UPD**

I case if you want to use exactly the same `PATH` as on the build stage, you can use

```
RUN echo "export PATH=${PATH}" >> /root/.bashrc
```

Comment: You can use double quotes, for example, `RUN echo "export PATH=${PATH}" >> /root/.bashrc` will get PATH  value from the environment of the build stage.